# How would I Emit a discriminated union?

Tags: reflection, f#

If I have something like this:

```
type public ServiceActionType =
    | ServiceRequest
    | ServiceResponse
    | ServiceEventInvocation
    | ServiceEventSubscriptionRequest
    | ServiceMetadataRequest
```

how do I then add one of those items to the stack, as in:

```
IlGen.Emit(OpCodes.???, ???)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, discriminated unions are compiled as class hierarchies (meaning that there is a new sub-class for every case of the discriminated union). However, in your case, the situation is simpler, because none of the cases carries any values.

If you look at the compiled code, you'll see that the generated .NET representation gives you something like:

```
class ServiceActionType {
  public static ServiceActionType ServiceRequest { get; }
  public static ServiceActionType ServiceResponse { get; }
  public static ServiceActionType ServiceEventInvocation { get; }
  // etc. for all the other cases
}
```

This means that, if you want to construct one of the values of the discriminated union, you just need to emit a call to the getter method of the (static) property representing the case you want.

If you had a case with arguments, say `ServiceRequest of RequestInfo`, then the generated class would include a `NewServiceRequest` method instead, which would take the necessary parameters:

```
public static ServiceActionType NewServiceRequest(RequestInfo info);
```

That said, I'm not entirely sure why you want to do this, so emitting code might not be the best approach. You can also consider using F# quotations - which can be compiled to dynamic methods - and creating a quotation that represents construction of a DU case is quite easy using `Expr.NewUnionCase`.

Comment: `I'm not entirely sure why you want to do this`, trying to wrap a user defined interface in a concrete class (for service type calls). Unless there is a better way to do this?

Comment: @sircodesalot Not sure I fully understand - are you trying to automatically build wrappers around F# discriminated unions to match some class/interface type that is provided by the caller? (It sounds interesting...)

Comment: User creates a service side class that exposes entry via some interface. When consuming said service, user calls Conntect<T>() (where T is interface type) which builds a concrete proxy around the interface to call the service. Part of submitting the request requires determining what kind of call is being made, hence I needed to know how to add the call type to the Emit stack.

Answer (score 6):

The existing answers are good, but note that the `Microsoft.FSharp.Reflection` namespace has some helpers that make it easy to get the members that you care about:

```
open Reflection
let cases = FSharpType.GetUnionCases(typeof<ServiceActionType>)
let serviceRequestMethod = FSharpValue.PreComputeUnionConstructorInfo(cases.[0])
```

The result is the same as `typeof<ServiceActionType>.GetMethod("get_ServiceRequest")` but you don't have to worry about knowing the compiled form, which can vary depending on whether the union cases have fields.

Comment: +1 Good point. This is certainly a better way to get the method info object!

Answer (score 2):

Let's take `ServiceActionType.ServiceRequest` for example.

I put the following in LINQPad (F# Program mode) to get the IL (but you could use `ildasm.exe` for the same purpose):

```
type public ServiceActionType =
    | ServiceRequest
    | ServiceResponse
    | ServiceEventInvocation
    | ServiceEventSubscriptionRequest
    | ServiceMetadataRequest

ServiceRequest.Dump()
```

and it gave me:

```
IL_0001:  call        Query_qdoovg+ServiceActionType.get_ServiceRequest
IL_0006:  call        LINQPad.FSharpExtensions.Extensions.Dump

Dump:
IL_0000:  nop         
IL_0001:  ldarg.0     
IL_0002:  box         03 00 00 1B 
IL_0007:  call        LINQPad.FSharpExtensions.Extensions.Dump
IL_000C:  ret         

ServiceActionType.get_ServiceMetadataRequest:
IL_0000:  ldsfld      Query_qdoovg+ServiceActionType._unique_ServiceMetadataRequest
IL_0005:  ret         

ServiceActionType.get_IsServiceMetadataRequest:
IL_0000:  ldarg.0     
IL_0001:  call        Query_qdoovg+ServiceActionType.get_Tag
IL_0006:  ldc.i4.4    
IL_0007:  ceq         
IL_0009:  ret         

ServiceActionType.get_ServiceEventSubscriptionRequest:
IL_0000:  ldsfld      Query_qdoovg+ServiceActionType._unique_ServiceEventSubscriptionRequest
IL_0005:  ret         

ServiceActionType.get_IsServiceEventSubscriptionRequest:
IL_0000:  ldarg.0     
IL_0001:  call        Query_qdoovg+ServiceActionType.get_Tag
IL_0006:  ldc.i4.3    
IL_0007:  ceq         
IL_0009:  ret         

ServiceActionType.get_ServiceEventInvocation:
IL_0000:  ldsfld      Query_qdoovg+ServiceActionType._unique_ServiceEventInvocation
IL_0005:  ret         

ServiceActionType.get_IsServiceEventInvocation:
IL_0000:  ldarg.0     
IL_0001:  call        Query_qdoovg+ServiceActionType.get_Tag
IL_0006:  ldc.i4.2    
IL_0007:  ceq         
IL_0009:  ret         

ServiceActionType.get_ServiceResponse:
IL_0000:  ldsfld      Query_qdoovg+ServiceActionType._unique_ServiceResponse
IL_0005:  ret         

ServiceActionType.get_IsServiceResponse:
IL_0000:  ldarg.0     
IL_0001:  call        Query_qdoovg+ServiceActionType.get_Tag
IL_0006:  ldc.i4.1    
IL_0007:  ceq         
IL_0009:  ret         

ServiceActionType.get_ServiceRequest:
IL_0000:  ldsfld      Query_qdoovg+ServiceActionType._unique_ServiceRequest
IL_0005:  ret         

ServiceActionType.get_IsServiceRequest:
IL_0000:  ldarg.0     
IL_0001:  call        Query_qdoovg+ServiceActionType.get_Tag
IL_0006:  ldc.i4.0    
IL_0007:  ceq         
IL_0009:  ret         

ServiceActionType.get_Tag:
IL_0000:  ldarg.0     
IL_0001:  ldfld       Query_qdoovg+ServiceActionType._tag
IL_0006:  ret         

ServiceActionType.__DebugDisplay:
IL_0000:  ldstr       "%+0.8A"
IL_0005:  newobj      Microsoft.FSharp.Core.PrintfFormat<Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpFunc<Query_qdoovg+ServiceActionType,System.String>,Microsoft.FSharp.Core.Unit,System.String,System.String,System.String>..ctor
IL_000A:  call        Microsoft.FSharp.Core.ExtraTopLevelOperators.PrintFormatToString
IL_000F:  ldarg.0     
IL_0010:  callvirt    Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpFunc<Query_qdoovg+ServiceActionType,System.String>.Invoke
IL_0015:  ret         

ServiceActionType.CompareTo:
IL_0000:  nop         
IL_0001:  ldarg.0     
IL_0002:  ldnull      
IL_0003:  cgt.un      
IL_0005:  brfalse.s   IL_0027
IL_0007:  ldarg.1     
IL_0008:  ldnull      
IL_0009:  cgt.un      
IL_000B:  brfalse.s   IL_0025
IL_000D:  ldarg.0     
IL_000E:  ldfld       Query_qdoovg+ServiceActionType._tag
IL_0013:  stloc.0     
IL_0014:  ldarg.1     
IL_0015:  ldfld       Query_qdoovg+ServiceActionType._tag
IL_001A:  stloc.1     
IL_001B:  ldloc.0     
IL_001C:  ldloc.1     
IL_001D:  bne.un.s    IL_0021
IL_001F:  ldc.i4.0    
IL_0020:  ret         
IL_0021:  ldloc.0     
IL_0022:  ldloc.1     
IL_0023:  sub         
IL_0024:  ret         
IL_0025:  ldc.i4.1    
IL_0026:  ret         
IL_0027:  ldarg.1     
IL_0028:  ldnull      
IL_0029:  cgt.un      
IL_002B:  brfalse.s   IL_002F
IL_002D:  ldc.i4.m1   
IL_002E:  ret         
IL_002F:  ldc.i4.0    
IL_0030:  ret         

ServiceActionType.CompareTo:
IL_0000:  nop         
IL_0001:  ldarg.0     
IL_0002:  ldarg.1     
IL_0003:  unbox.any   Query_qdoovg.ServiceActionType
IL_0008:  call        Query_qdoovg+ServiceActionType.CompareTo
IL_000D:  ret         

ServiceActionType.CompareTo:
IL_0000:  nop         
IL_0001:  ldarg.1     
IL_0002:  unbox.any   Query_qdoovg.ServiceActionType
IL_0007:  stloc.0     
IL_0008:  ldarg.0     
IL_0009:  ldnull      
IL_000A:  cgt.un      
IL_000C:  brfalse.s   IL_0033
IL_000E:  ldarg.1     
IL_000F:  unbox.any   Query_qdoovg.ServiceActionType
IL_0014:  ldnull      
IL_0015:  cgt.un      
IL_0017:  brfalse.s   IL_0031
IL_0019:  ldarg.0     
IL_001A:  ldfld       Query_qdoovg+ServiceActionType._tag
IL_001F:  stloc.1     
IL_0020:  ldloc.0     
IL_0021:  ldfld       Query_qdoovg+ServiceActionType._tag
IL_0026:  stloc.2     
IL_0027:  ldloc.1     
IL_0028:  ldloc.2     
IL_0029:  bne.un.s    IL_002D
IL_002B:  ldc.i4.0    
IL_002C:  ret         
IL_002D:  ldloc.1     
IL_002E:  ldloc.2     
IL_002F:  sub         
IL_0030:  ret         
IL_0031:  ldc.i4.1    
IL_0032:  ret         
IL_0033:  ldarg.1     
IL_0034:  unbox.any   Query_qdoovg.ServiceActionType
IL_0039:  ldnull      
IL_003A:  cgt.un      
IL_003C:  brfalse.s   IL_0040
IL_003E:  ldc.i4.m1   
IL_003F:  ret         
IL_0040:  ldc.i4.0    
IL_0041:  ret         

ServiceActionType.GetHashCode:
IL_0000:  nop         
IL_0001:  ldarg.0     
IL_0002:  ldnull      
IL_0003:  cgt.un      
IL_0005:  brfalse.s   IL_003C
IL_0007:  ldc.i4.0    
IL_0008:  stloc.0     
IL_0009:  ldarg.0     
IL_000A:  call        Query_qdoovg+ServiceActionType.get_Tag
IL_000F:  switch      (IL_0028, IL_002C, IL_0030, IL_0034, IL_0038)
IL_0028:  ldc.i4.0    
IL_0029:  stloc.0     
IL_002A:  ldloc.0     
IL_002B:  ret         
IL_002C:  ldc.i4.1    
IL_002D:  stloc.0     
IL_002E:  ldloc.0     
IL_002F:  ret         
IL_0030:  ldc.i4.2    
IL_0031:  stloc.0     
IL_0032:  ldloc.0     
IL_0033:  ret         
IL_0034:  ldc.i4.3    
IL_0035:  stloc.0     
IL_0036:  ldloc.0     
IL_0037:  ret         
IL_0038:  ldc.i4.4    
IL_0039:  stloc.0     
IL_003A:  ldloc.0     
IL_003B:  ret         
IL_003C:  ldc.i4.0    
IL_003D:  ret         

ServiceActionType.GetHashCode:
IL_0000:  nop         
IL_0001:  ldarg.0     
IL_0002:  call        Microsoft.FSharp.Core.LanguagePrimitives.get_GenericEqualityComparer
IL_0007:  call        Query_qdoovg+ServiceActionType.GetHashCode
IL_000C:  ret         

ServiceActionType.Equals:
IL_0000:  nop         
IL_0001:  ldarg.0     
IL_0002:  ldnull      
IL_0003:  cgt.un      
IL_0005:  brfalse.s   IL_0026
IL_0007:  ldarg.1     
IL_0008:  isinst      Query_qdoovg.ServiceActionType
IL_000D:  stloc.0     
IL_000E:  ldloc.0     
IL_000F:  brfalse.s   IL_0024
IL_0011:  ldarg.0     
IL_0012:  ldfld       Query_qdoovg+ServiceActionType._tag
IL_0017:  stloc.1     
IL_0018:  ldloc.0     
IL_0019:  ldfld       Query_qdoovg+ServiceActionType._tag
IL_001E:  stloc.2     
IL_001F:  ldloc.1     
IL_0020:  ldloc.2     
IL_0021:  ceq         
IL_0023:  ret         
IL_0024:  ldc.i4.0    
IL_0025:  ret         
IL_0026:  ldarg.1     
IL_0027:  ldnull      
IL_0028:  cgt.un      
IL_002A:  ldc.i4.0    
IL_002B:  ceq         
IL_002D:  ret         

ServiceActionType.Equals:
IL_0000:  nop         
IL_0001:  ldarg.0     
IL_0002:  ldnull      
IL_0003:  cgt.un      
IL_0005:  brfalse.s   IL_0022
IL_0007:  ldarg.1     
IL_0008:  ldnull      
IL_0009:  cgt.un      
IL_000B:  brfalse.s   IL_0020
IL_000D:  ldarg.0     
IL_000E:  ldfld       Query_qdoovg+ServiceActionType._tag
IL_0013:  stloc.0     
IL_0014:  ldarg.1     
IL_0015:  ldfld       Query_qdoovg+ServiceActionType._tag
IL_001A:  stloc.1     
IL_001B:  ldloc.0     
IL_001C:  ldloc.1     
IL_001D:  ceq         
IL_001F:  ret         
IL_0020:  ldc.i4.0    
IL_0021:  ret         
IL_0022:  ldarg.1     
IL_0023:  ldnull      
IL_0024:  cgt.un      
IL_0026:  ldc.i4.0    
IL_0027:  ceq         
IL_0029:  ret         

ServiceActionType.Equals:
IL_0000:  nop         
IL_0001:  ldarg.1     
IL_0002:  isinst      Query_qdoovg.ServiceActionType
IL_0007:  stloc.0     
IL_0008:  ldloc.0     
IL_0009:  brfalse.s   IL_0013
IL_000B:  ldarg.0     
IL_000C:  ldloc.0     
IL_000D:  call        Query_qdoovg+ServiceActionType.Equals
IL_0012:  ret         
IL_0013:  ldc.i4.0    
IL_0014:  ret         

ServiceActionType..ctor:
IL_0000:  ldarg.0     
IL_0001:  call        System.Object..ctor
IL_0006:  ldarg.0     
IL_0007:  ldarg.1     
IL_0008:  stfld       Query_qdoovg+ServiceActionType._tag
IL_000D:  ret
```

Where `IL_0001: call Query_qdoovg+ServiceActionType.get_ServiceRequest` is the bit that does a `call` instruction to get the `ServiceActionType.ServiceRequest` value on the stack.

Which could be emitted like: `il.Emit(OpCodes.Call, typeof<ServiceActionType>.GetMethod("get_ServiceRequest"))`